# Stored procedure to insert data into Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure or function defined in my Postgresql database:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_val(int)
    $body$
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        insert into test (val)
        values($23);
      END LOOP;
   END;
   $body$ Language 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

I just want to insert this data inside of a loop, but I get always this error:

> Syntaxfehler bei »begin«

Is maybe that I missed something in my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the error message since it's not in English, but I can see a few problems in your code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_val(IN val int) RETURNS VOID  AS 
$body$
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        insert into test (val)
        values($23);
      END LOOP;
   END;
   $body$ Language 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

You were missing the return type, you were missing `AS` and you have forgotten to name the in argument.

Comment: Hi THX for your answer, you were right, I mist the Returns Void As. I executed the function and I didn't get any errors this time, but also not row in the table test was affected, I mean didn't insert nothing. Can you PLS help me? P.S: The error that I got just means syntax error in $body$, sorry for the not translation

Comment: well it will not result in a row being created in the table until you call it!  `select insert_val(1)` for example!

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You forgot

```
RETURNS void AS
```

between the first and the second line.

But that will only take care of the syntax. The `$23` is clearly wrong since there are no 23 function arguments. Did you mean `$1`?

Comment: Hi, yes I added already the values to insert like: values($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10). I fixed already the syntax error of RETURNS void AS, but I still don't get the correct result

Comment: Explain your problem.